# UIWebView: Can I disable the javascript alert() inside any web page?

Tags: javascript, ios, uiwebview

I am using `UIWebView` to load a URL.

Inside the page of that URL, it uses `alert("whatever msg")` as JavaScript. My `UIWebView` will pop up a window and show that alert message.

Is there a way to disable this kind of popup window or JavaScript alert window?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Add this after your web view has loaded its content

```
[MyWebView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"window.alert=null;"];
```

Comment: Very helpful, it is working. 

I have mention that I have to put this message in webViewDidStartLoad delegate method, just for other people who may want to know

Comment: This did not work for me since the JS that shows the alert was executed before the rendering of the page completed. I ended up blocking it on the native level: http://stackoverflow.com/a/21698251/154915

Comment: Even put it in webViewDidStartLoad does not work, either

Answer (score 13):

You can bind `window.alert` to another function. So:

```
window.alert = function() {
  //does nothing so effectively "disables" alert
};
```

Make sure you do this before you call any alerts. The neat thing about this is you can customize the way you display messages to the user. So you could override `window.alert` to log to the console (for debugging purposes) or you can render it on the page (with a lightbox or something similar).

Comment: No problem. pop850's answer is probably what you want to accept since it addresses your concern directly.

Comment: From my point of view this answer addresses the issue more gracefully, as `var a = null; a();` is a JavaScript runtime error.

Answer (score 1):

Since a `UIWebView` translates all Javascript alerts into native `UIAlertViews` it is fairly simple to block it on the native end. Looking into `UIAlertView.h` there is only one public method for showing an alert which is conveniently called: `- (void)show;`.

```
@interface UIAlertView (Blocker)
@end

#import "UIAlertView+Blocker.h"

@implementation UIAlertView (Blocker)

- (void)show {
   return;
}
@end
```

You can find the answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/21698251/2377378

Answer (score 0):

```
let script = """
                window.alert=window.confirm=window.prompt=function(n){},
                [].slice.apply(document.querySelectorAll('iframe')).forEach(function(n){if(n.contentWindow != window){n.contentWindow.alert=n.contentWindow.confirm=n.contentWindow.prompt=function(n){}}})
                """
    webView.evaluateJavaScript(script, completionHandler: nil)
```