# Capture (and prevent) alert() modal in UIWebView

Tags: javascript, ios, objective-c, uiwebview

I'm trying to prevent an `alert()` modal from appearing when used in a UIWebView. [Many](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3400429/uiwebview-can-i-disable-the-javascript-alert-inside-any-web-page) [others](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3156140/disable-the-alert-box-in-uiwebview) suggest the use of overriding `window.alert` like this:

```
- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)thisView {
    [MyWebView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"window.alert=null;"];
}
```

However in the page I'm loading the `alert()` is called before the page has finished loading.

Rather than disabling alert at the JS level, how can I override/disable it at the iOS level?

Comment: Have you seen http://stackoverflow.com/a/1585854/836214 ? It seems to cover exactly this.

Comment: Since timing was an issue for me as well I ended up blocking the alert on a native level: http://stackoverflow.com/a/21698251/154915