# How to block Javascript alert|confirm|promt in UIWebView before render completed?

Tags: javascript, ios, objective-c, uiwebview

There are multiple questions on SO already addressing similar issues but none answers my exact type of question. Most of the answers involves running a JS snippet and overloading the alert method as such: `window.alert = function() {};`

The problem I am having is that the webpage loaded (which I have no control over the content) opens an alert before the rendering of the whole page completes.

Because of this I cannot use the: `- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView` delegate method to run the JS snippet. In addition running the same snippet in `- (void)webViewDidStartLoad:(UIWebView *)webView` won't do me any good since it executes before the DOM is loaded.

Similar questions:

- [Capture (and prevent) alert() modal in UIWebView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21070399/capture-and-prevent-alert-modal-in-uiwebview)
- [Can I handle alert inside UIWebViewDelegate?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1565102/can-i-handle-alert-inside-uiwebviewdelegate)
- [UIWebView: Can I disable the javascript alert() inside any web page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3400429/uiwebview-can-i-disable-the-javascript-alert-inside-any-web-page)

Any pointers on this?

Comment: can you move the script that create the alert to one line above </body>?

Comment: Are you suggesting that I preload the HTML and parse-out the alerts code and move it? I was looking for a bit more robust solution.

Comment: if you have no control over anything else thn yes i guess i am, cant see how else you might do it if you dont override alert

Answer (score 9, accepted):

After experimenting a bit with the suggested solutions regarding injecting a Javascript I fell back on the native platform.

Since a `UIWebView` translates all Javascript alerts into native `UIAlertViews` it is fairly simple to block it on the native end. Looking into `UIAlertView.h` there is only one public method for showing an alert which is conveniently called: `- (void)show;`.

This method can easily be either overridden in a subclass or through a category. I ended up using a category since [the documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIAlertView_Class/UIAlertView/UIAlertView.html) mentions a warning for subclassing `UIAlertView`.

```
@interface UIAlertView (Blocker)
@end

#import "UIAlertView+Blocker.h"

@implementation UIAlertView (Blocker)

- (void)show {
   return;
}
@end
```

Importing this category in the view controller that holds the `UIWebView` will block all instances of `UIAlertView` and in turn also all JS alerts.

I find this solution more robust since it does not rely on injecting Javascripts, changing HTML or using a third party library. It is also unrelated to timing (the JS-alert code can be in the header, body or in some third party lib).

Comment: Using categories to override methods is [strongly discouraged by Apple](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5272612/404321)

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the result may vary based on the rendering engine, there are a few ways, what seemed to work for me what this:

```
alert("something");
alert = function(){};
alert("awesome");
```

http://jsfiddle.net/g5S5M/
I know that the V8 engine that chrome uses is not the same as the one that firefox or IE use, so  when making complex web applications one has to really start thinking because not all browsers interpred javascript the sameway.

One thing that you might want to look at is third party libraries that override this function, as in if you tell alert to be blank and right after another script tells it not to be blank, so ether remove that library, change the execution order or modify that library.

Comment: I can confirm that on webpages that display their alert _after_ the whole page has been loaded (webViewDidFinishLoad: has been called) this workaround does work. But that problem I was having now is that the alert is opened before everything is rendered.
Are you suggesting that I inject some kind of JS-lib to handle this?

Comment: You could wrap it in a isReady function http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/

Comment: I ended up using a native solution to solve this problem. It feels more robust and is more within my own comfort zone.